# How can I make mdframed boxes break at the bottom of the page?

Tags: vertical-alignment, mdframed

I'm trying to get [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) to split at the bottom of my page, such that there is no white space between the bottom of the frame and the footer. At the moment I have this:

[image]

I'd like to have mdframed split right at the bottom of the white space, instead of leaving a gap between it and the bottom border. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: use `\enlargethispage{2cm}`

Comment: Ah!, thank you very much. That works like a charm on the first page. Can I do something similar if the mdframed splits over more than one pagebreak?

Comment: Please try: `\makeatletter\preto\mdf@put@frame@ii{\enlargethispage{2cm}}\makeatother and after `\end{mdframed}` you must reset it `\enlargethispage{-2cm}`.

Comment: Using the above the command: `\makeatletter\preto\mdf@put@frame@ii{\enlargethispage{2cm}}\makeatother` the mdframed do not change, regardless of the value inside \enlargethispage

Comment: Can you provide a MWE please.

Comment: I've found a different solution to my problem, by using the method here [link](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/framed-tikz/)

I needed to have entire pages coloured in the same colour as the environment i.e. if the environment starts halfway through page 6 and extends to halfway through page 8, I need the second half of p6, all of p7 and the first half of p8 to be green(say). Also, the colour must extend to the edge of the page. 

I'll post a MWE as soon as I get time, I think this is an interesting problem to solve that many people will use.

Comment: can you provide an answer please (with an example)? So it will help other users.